# Displaying CSV file with centre point data but no XY data?

Tags: arcmap

How do I convert this csv data to points in arcgis? Please see screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of CSV file attribute table]

Comment: Looks like a perfectly normal lat,lon pair to me. Maybe you should state what the XY you're familiar with looks like.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Coordinates look okay for me as well, as @Vince wrote. I can even say more that it is possible to visualise them. You just need to parse the column `"Community Center Point"`. The first thing you need to do is to create two additional columns (both `float`, `precision` 12, `length` 20). Second thing is to apply `Field Calculator` to be able to extract `X` and `Y` separately. Should be not a big deal.

Comment: Can you please add a link to your csv, or even just a screenshot of the first few rows open in a program like notepad++, ultraedit, or notepad?

Answer (score 1):

See preprocessing notes below.

In order to create points, you can use the Make XY event layer tool or right click on the table to add XY events. Choose a spatial reference (what CRS was used in the collection of the latlong on your CSV?). Make sure the longitude column is selected for X values, and latitude selected for Y values. Once created in this way, export to a shapefile or feature class. (If in arcpy, Copy Features tool works for this.)

A note on preprocessing: you need to have lat and long in separate columns. I find this easiest to do in Excel before bringing in the CSV using text to columns, but you can probably create new fields (type = DOUBLE) on the table in arcmap and use the Field Calculator. Sample field calculator code:

Codeblock:

```
def getlat(latlong):
    tmp = latlong.split(", ")[0]
    return float(tmp[1:]) #drop the (

def getlong(latlong):
    tmp = latlong.split(", ")[1]
    return float(tmp[:-1]) #drop the )
```

Expression on long / x field:

```
getlong(!latlongfieldname!)
```

Expression on lat / y field:

```
getlat(!latlongfieldname!)
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I'm just an average ArcGIS user. I've got little or no programming knowledge.

Comment: Which option are you trying? A) Edit input csv first, or B) use field calculator?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried editing it in Excel by splitting columns but I was not successful. I'd be grateful if you can teach me how I can edit it in Excel.

Comment: This might need to be a separate question, but in general you can use "text to columns" in Data. Use comma as the delimiter. Then use find/replace to remove the parenthesis, e.g. Find ) and replace with nothing. Find ( and replace with nothing. Save your file and import into ArcGIS.

Comment: I suppose @smiller is referring to formulas in Excel. In a new cell use this formula `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2;"(";"");")";"")` to get rid of `"("` and `")"`. The next step is extracting lat everything before `", "` and lon everything after `", "`. lat with formula `=LEFT(B2; FIND(",";B2)-1)` and lon with formula `RIGHT(C2; LEN(C2)-FIND(",";C2)-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `File > Add Data > Add XY Data` in ArcMap to spatialise CSVs that hold point coordinates, as smiller has pointed out. However, you'll need to clean yours up before you import it, because `Add XY Data` won't be able to 'see' the coordinates while they're in one column. Its a pretty simple tool with a rigid interface.

The recommendation to clean the data in Excel is probably the easiest approach, just be aware of known issues like surprise date conversions. Do it like this:

- Make a copy of your dataset (never mess with the original!)
- Open Excel, nav to the Data tab, click 'From Text'
- Select your csv copy, choose 'delimited text' radio button, and tick 'my data has headers'.
- On the next screen, tick 'Comma'. At this point you should see your 'Community Center Point' field get split into two. Click Finish.
- Once your data is imported, select the two columns that contain coordinates, and use Find and Replace to get rid of the brackets (replace them with nothing).
- Edit the column names to something sensible like 'X_coord'/'Y_coord' or 'Long'/'Lat'.
- Save your edited dataset and use `Add XY Data` in Arc to get points. Don't forget to specify a CRS.

If you find that other fields besides your coordinate data get split up when you tick 'Comma' (e.g. fields with descriptive sentences in them), Excel is no longer the tool for you - if you don't tick 'Comma', the importer will dump the whole CSV into column A, and you'll be stuck trying to separate everything. Your other options are:

- Install QGIS and use its delimited text importer, which is far better than Arc's. Use the 'custom delimiters' option under File Format, tick Comma, and add `()` to the Others field.
- Open a copy of your CSV in a good text editor like Notepad++ or Ultraedit, use alt+click-and-drag to select only the coordinate data, and then use find and replace inside the selection to get rid of the brackets. Replace `(` with nothing, and `)` with a comma. Then correct the column names on row 1. Save and import to Arc.